# Can't view embedded Google Maps because "Internet Explorer has modified this page to help prevent cross-site scripting"

Tags: google-maps, internet-explorer-8, xss

The offending page is http://beta.westlake.school.nz/school-details if viewed using IE8

Comment: But this is from Google Maps, I see no reason why IE8 is blocking it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In my case, this seemed to be caused by a couple of single quotes in the `hnear` argument in the Google URL.  Removing the quotes in both the `iframe src` and the `a href` attributes fixed the problem.

For example,

```
<a href="http://maps.google.com/maps/ms?source=embed&amp;hl=fr&amp;geocode=&amp;aq=&amp;ie=UTF8&amp;hq=&amp;hnear=Ch%C3%A2teau-d'%C5%92x,+Riviera-Pays-d'Enhaut,+Vaud,+Switzerland&amp;msa=0&amp;ll=46.472921,7.130213&amp;spn=0.021578,0.055747&amp;msid=208989902893156915814.0004a534bae54848e2335">
```

became

```
<a href="http://maps.google.com/maps/ms?source=embed&amp;hl=fr&amp;geocode=&amp;aq=&amp;ie=UTF8&amp;hq=&amp;hnear=Ch%C3%A2teau-d%C5%92x,+Riviera-Pays-dEnhaut,+Vaud,+Switzerland&amp;msa=0&amp;ll=46.472921,7.130213&amp;spn=0.021578,0.055747&amp;msid=208989902893156915814.0004a534bae54848e2335">
```

Not sure whether that's because Google didn't need the argument in my case, or whether it could handle the modification gracefully.

Comment: Yours was the only answer. If it worked for you it might work for others. I no longer work on this site so I don't know if it was ever resolved.